# How to create content database and site collection in managed client object model?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-clientobject

We are developing remote asp.net application for SharePoint Foundation 2010. We want to create content database and site collection for that content database programatically. I am searching on internet. I found many examples which uses Server Object Model. I am not able to find any article which uses Managed Client Object Model. Is there any way to create content database and site collection in managed client object model ?

Comment: Did you tried _anything_ so far?

Comment: no. I tried to find built in classes for client object model which are used in server object. but not able to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately thier is nothing in COM which can help you in attaching a content database to a web application and then to create a sitecollection on it.

You can use admin.asmx webservice alternatively which would be available under central admin webapplication

```
http://CAURL/_vti_adm/admin.asmx
```

This can help you in creating sitecollection but i don't see OOTB service to create Content database for that you would have to create your custom web service

Comment: Thanks for reply. I gone through custom web service createtion tutorial http://nikspatel.wordpress.com/2012/02/29/step-by-step-building-custom-wcf-services-hosted-in-sharepoint-part-i/. Is it mandatory that the custom wcf service and sharepoint server must reside on same machine or they can reside on different machine ?

Comment: I want to use SharePoint 2010 Server Object model and server object model runs on SharePoint only. So I have asked above question.

Comment: As per your requirements yes it is mandatory to host your custom service on SharePoint Farm